# echo count number of rows in codeigniter view with link

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to count the number of rows and display it in my view with link..when user click on the number the link will go to the particular url..

This is my model:

```
 function getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2)
 {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('requirements');
    $this->db->join('role','role.role_id=requirements.role_id');
    $this->db->where('created_date >=', $date1);
    $this->db->where('created_date <=', $date2);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //echo $this->db->last_query();
    $rowcount = $query->num_rows();
    //echo $rowcount;
    return $query->result();
}
```

Another Model:

```
function getrequirements()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('requirements');
    $this->db->join('role','role.role_id=requirements.role_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
     // echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function view_requirements_bydate($date1="",$date2="")
{
    $data["msg"]="";
    $data = array(
        'total_item' => $this->ReportModel->getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2)
                  );
    if($date1=='' && $date2=='' )
    {
      $data['view_requirements'] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirements();
    }
    else
    {
      $data['view_requirements'] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2);
    }
    $this->load->view('Reports/view_requirements_bydate',$data);
}
```

view:(display the count number here)..

```
<body>
<h4>No of Requirements:</h4>
</body>
```

This is my Table code:

```
<div class="box-body">
          <table id="" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
               <th>Role Name</th>
              <th>Vacancies</th>
              <th>Experience</th>
              <th>Job Description</th>
              <th>Hiring Contact Number</th>
              <th>Hiring Contact Name</th>
              <th>Date</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>

             <?php 
               foreach ($view_requirements as $idata) 
                {
                ?>


            <tbody>

                  <tr id="domain<?php echo $idata->req_id;?>">
                    <td><?php echo $idata->role_name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->vacancies;?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $idata->experience;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->jd;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->hiring_contact_number;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $idata->hiring_contact_name;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $idata->created_date;?></td>



                    </tr>



            <?php
          }
            ?>


            </tbody>

          </table>
```

Can anyone help me how to do this
Thank you..

Comment: from where did you get the particular url.Is it from database?

Comment: is this count? $data['view_requirements']

Comment: print_r($data) in view and see what is the result? @bharathi

Comment: @bharathi you need count of which model function ?

Comment: function getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2) this model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model 1**

```
function getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2)
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('requirements');
    $this->db->join('role','role.role_id=requirements.role_id');
    $this->db->where('created_date >=', $date1);
    $this->db->where('created_date <=', $date2);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

---

**Model 2**

```
function getrequirements()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('requirements');
    $this->db->join('role','role.role_id=requirements.role_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

---

**Controller**

```
function view_requirements_bydate($date1="",$date2="")
{
    $data["msg"]="";

    if($date1 =='' && $date2 =='' )
    {
        $data['view_requirements'] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirements();
    }
    else
    {
        $result_array = $this->ReportModel->getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2);

        $data['total_item'] = count($result_array);
        $data['view_requirements'] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2);

    }
    $this->load->view('Reports/view_requirements_bydate',$data);
}
```

---

**View**

```
<body>
    <h4>echo $total_item;</h4>  // or print_r($total_item)
</body>
```

Comment: ya it's working...but now i can't display the table values..before i can display the table values depending on the date ranges

Comment: `foreach($view_requirements as $item){ echo $item['field_name'];}`

Comment: where i have to write this foreach($view_requirements as $item){ echo $item['field_name'];}

Comment: change this `$idata->req_id;` to this `$idata['req_id'];`

Comment: check your array. `print_r($idata)`Seems your array is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136213/discussion-between-abdulla-nilam-and-bharathi).

Answer (score 0):

In your view page add

```
<body>
<h4>No of Requirements:<a href="your url here"><?php echo count($data);?></a></h4>
</body>
```

Comment: it display value as 0

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<h4>No of Requirements:<a href="your url here"><?php echo $view_requirements?></a></h4>
</body>
```

try..

Comment: it display result as  array

Comment: i think you didn't get the value from the model.what did you get when you echo the  $data['view_requirements'] in the controller.

Comment: i wrote the that for view the values from the database ..$data['view_requirements'] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirements(); this is for display all requirements..$data['view_requirements'] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2); this is for display requirements depending on the date range

Comment: i just need u to do this echo $data['view_requirements']; in the controller..what is the result.may be something is problem with the model query.

Comment: my model code is working fine..i can print the value from my model

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

**Model**

```
function getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('requirements');
    $this->db->join('role','role.role_id=requirements.role_id');
    $this->db->where('created_date >=', $date1);
    $this->db->where('created_date <=', $date2);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $rowcount = $query->num_rows();
    return $rowcount;
}

function getrequirements()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('requirements');
    $this->db->join('role','role.role_id=requirements.role_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
     // echo $this->db->last_query();
    $rowcount = $query->num_rows();
    return $rowcount;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function view_requirements_bydate($date1="",$date2="")
{
    $data["msg"]="";
    $data["total_item"] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2);
    if($date1=='' && $date2=='' )
    {
        $data['view_requirements'] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirements();
    }
    else
    {
        $data['view_requirements'] = $this->ReportModel->getrequirementsdate($date1,$date2);
    }
    $this->load->view('Reports/view_requirements_bydate',$data);
}
```

**View**

```
<body>
    <h4>No of Requirements:</h4>
    <a href="REDIRECT_URL"><?php echo $view_requirements; ?></a>
</body>
```

Comment: print_r($data) in controller and give me what it displays

Comment: @bharathi there must be something wrong with your query

Comment: @bharathi print your query and try that query in mysql console

Comment: @bharathi return $rowcount; in model

Comment: ya when i return $rowcount it display number correctly

Comment: @bharathi then use my answer after returning that $rowcount

Comment: it again display array

Comment: print that array @bharathi here

Comment: where i have to print that array

Comment: display me @bharathi

Comment: <h4>No of Requirements:<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Reports/view_requirements_bydate"><?php echo $view_requirements; ?></h4>

Comment: @bharathi what is the output of echo $view_requirements;? display it to me

Comment: No of Requirements:Array

Comment: do this man: print_r($view_requirements); don't you know how to print an array?

Comment: @bharathi did you changed your model? like this: return $rowcount;?

Comment: @bharathi-you are getting the array from the model function getrequirements();

Comment: @VimalS yes, but I told him that just return count, but i thunk he is not getting what i want to tell him

Comment: @bharathi just return this `return $rowcount;` if you want count.

Comment: @bharathi-there is something wrong with the logic in the if cases in the controller.can you please add the getrequirements(); function in the question

Comment: just return count instead of query result. @bharathi